# PHP Multi language web service for android

Tags: php, android

I am write web service(PHP) for android application and I have on doubt, how can I manage multi language functionality. could help guys?

Comment: Have a look at a library like RetroFit (https://square.github.io/retrofit/). What you will want to think of is that the Web Service will sit on a server, to which the Android App will (thru say RetroFit) make a HTTPS call to that service. When/If you hit issues with the code then come back with examples and we can try help you some more!

Comment: What do you mean by multi language functionality?  You want to return results in different languages?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle multi-languages in response - PHP in different ways, mostly used way is to identify the language from the client request as given below. Upon the client request you can change your response.

```
$language = $_GET['languageSelection'];
```

You may set **charset** as given below to support different languages in you responses.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }   
    mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
```